# restore database using bak file - resorting to old date?

Tags: sql-server

Last night I made a full backup of my DB in SQL server management, when I restore the DB instead of being complete - it is missing all its data from the last few month.

The full backup was taken last night and is market as - 07/05/2014 16:54 
However the information in the tables has restored itself to 24/02/2014

any help would be greatly appreciated -

Comment: Did it face some constraint issue regarding Disk Space? What is the approximate size of your DB? in MB or GB??

Comment: I don't think so, the DB is only 66.264 KB and we have lots of space on the server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your backup file contain multiple backups (known as backup sets), and are you restoring just the earliest backup set from the backup file?

To see the backup sets in a file run the following and note the `Position` column, which denotes the backup set:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK='mybackup.bak'
```

To [restore a specific backup set from a backup](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx#restoring_using_FILE_n_FG):

```
RESTORE DATABASE ... WITH FILE = <position from previous statement>
```

#### Why does this happen?

If you use the same filename every time in your backup script (e.g. `BACKUP DATABASE MyDb TO DISK='backup.bak'`), and that file is not deleted or changed between backups, then your backup is added to the backup sets in that file. If you then run `RESTORE DATABASE ...` without a `WITH FILE=<position>` clause, you will always restore the first backup set in the backup media - usually your earliest one.

#### The details:

The `RESTORE HEADERONLY` command is useful for a backup file (if you are looking at it on a different server to the one it was created on). You can also see the backups on the server that created them by running the command:

```
SELECT backup_set_id, media_set_id, position, backup_finish_date 
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
```

If you want to check which backup set you just restored from a multi-file media then you can run:

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory
```

Note the `backup_set_id` which corresponds to the msdb `backupset` table and in turn to the media file and position within that file.

#### References:

From [MSDN: RESTORE Arguments (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178615.aspx):

> Backup Set Options
>
> FILE ={ backup_set_file_number | @backup_set_file_number }
>
> ...
>
> When not specified, the default is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I regularly take full backups but the date its restoring to seems like the date I first began to back up on.   I was unaware that a manual made .bak file could contain the previous versions - could you please expand on your answer?

Comment: Do you always back up to the same filename?

Comment: Hi Andy thank you for your reply - yes I do always backup to the same file name

Comment: I think that's your problem. See my expanded answer: use the msdb queries to verify that your media has multiple files in the media file, that your restores are only restoring the one at the first position, and that that one is the very earliest one you made.

Comment: Hi Andy - thank you very much you are totally correct, It is restoring from the first backup instead of the latest - I'm just working through the rest of your reply and will get back to you shortly.

Comment: Hi Andy - I have just finished working though you answer and have managed to restore all the data. You have really made my day. I honestly thought I had lost everything! Thank you very much for taking the time to reply I cant thank you enough

Comment: No problem. For future backups, I would include the timestamp in the filename in the format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH-MM-ss-fff`. This will help you manage your backups, purge old ones, and quickly restore exactly the one you want, and you will therefore have fewer problems if the database grows in size.